# Web API controller not working after several hits

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

After several hits Web API controller stopped loading but it starts working when I restarted it from IIS.

I am testing the API in the browser.

here is my controller with 2 query string for credential:

```
  [System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
    public class TestController1 : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage TestController1(string Username, string Password)
        {
            bool isvalid;
            string id = string.Empty;


            isvalid = //cheking credentials;

            if (isvalid)
            {
                var obj = //getting data from DB;
                if (obj.Count == 0)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Data not found", id)),
                        ReasonPhrase = "Localized message Data not found!"
                    };
                    return msg;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(string.Format("UserName or Password is Invalid")),
                    ReasonPhrase = "Identity not found!"
                };
                return msg;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Check the network part of you browser debug, and post the request and response here for us to be able to help you Mr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all functionality from `TestController1` and simply return Ok. If still fails, try catch/look for any exceptions - maybe in the IIS logs.

If it works without your functionality, enable it again in steps. Enable `//cheking credentials;` and `//getting data from DB` one at a time. Maybe you have a memory consumption problem?

Comment: Yes it works fine when I am just fetching OK.It happens on my localhost also. I think it happens between 90 to 100 hits.

Comment: So it also happens (after 90-100 hits) when you simply returns ok (status 200)?

Comment: No it doesn't happen for OK.

Comment: Is there any IIS restrictions?

Comment: No - not that i am aware of. I am pretty sure your problem is in one of the two calls;  `//cheking credentials` or `//getting data from DB`. Is it possible for you enable only one of them at a time, and test again?

Comment: It is only happens when I am hitting the Database.Ok let me check with that too.

Comment: Check that you Dispose your connection and similar resources. Are you working with a large dataset - many rows or blob/max columns?

Comment: Hey thank you very much you was right there was an issue with //cheking credentials.A connection was not getting close therefore due to connection pooling its all happening.

Comment: `using` is your friend. Glad to help